# What the heck is this thing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

[image: ball dude]

I was uploading mods (that have ABSOLUTELY nothing to do with entities) and this appeared. I don't know when but maybe someone else has seen it? Does anyone know?[image: mods folder mods]

[image: it says it is from minecraft]

Comment: Well looks like you just spawned it with that spawn egg... What mod is the spawn egg from?

Comment: What do you mean by 'uploading' mods? This entity/item is not from vanilla minecraft anyway...

Comment: It looks like you have installed a mod that adds in this thing. What mods do you currently have?

Comment: i meant "downloading mods", sorry :P and i have treecapitator, Damage indicator (which is how i got the hp), Floating ruins (which i took any mob info out), Instant Massive structures, Lucky Block, Crafting guide, Custom Chest Loot, Dynamic lights, Emerald and Obsidian mod, Expanded Redstone, Metallurgy, Inventory tweaks, Ropes Plus, Mob Drop Crops, and the Zoom Mod. i go into the coding and take out the mobs (i just don't like them) but i have never got any that add it that i know of, nor have i tried to make anytrhing. It disappears after a right click, though

Comment: and i spawned it, it only appears in the spawn egg.

Comment: I believe that you have also downloaded some other mods without knowing or you don't remember. Can you paste all your mods inside the mods folder into this question? Also, which mod loader are you using?

Comment: i just added my mods folder and i use Forge mod loader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're interested in finding out what something is from or what it is in Minecraft, I usually recommend using a mod called WAILA (What Am I Looking At). It's main function is not too surprising, it gives you a display containing the the block/entity type name as well as what mod it is from. So, I would recommend taking a look at that if you haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: i love the mod suggested... but it still says it is in minecraft

Comment: Add a link to the mod please?

Comment: So uh, how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/11-instant-massive-structures-mod-v10/

okay so the link says that the ball was part of it and i hate reading every single thing so i just kinda downloaded it (its like a surprise in a .jar file ^3^) and it says it spawns with a giant stadium (hence the huge negative hp amount) so it was basically a living soccer ball